# Getting object instead of list from selecting the store with NgRx

Tags: state, action, ngrx, store

I'm having problems retrieving an list from my state in the store, because the list is wrapped around with an object.

Here is my code

beer-list.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-beer-list',
  templateUrl: './beer-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./beer-list.component.css']
})
export class BeerListComponent implements OnInit {
  public beers$: Observable<Beer[]>;
  
  constructor(private store: Store<BeerState>) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.beers$ = this.store.select((state: BeerState) => state.beers);
    this.store.dispatch(getBeersOnTap());
  }
```

beer.actions.ts

```
export const getBeersOnTap = createAction(
  '[Beer List] Get beers'
);
export const getBeersOnTapSuccess = createAction(
  '[Beer List] Get beers succeeded',
  props<{beers: Beer[]}>()
);
export const getBeersOnTapFailed = createAction(
  '[Beer List] Get beers failed'
);
```

beer.reducers.ts

```
export interface BeerState {
  beers: Beer[];
}

export const initialState: BeerState = {
  beers: []
};

export const beerReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(getBeersOnTapSuccess, (state, {beers}) => ({...state, beers: beers}) // Payload comes from an effect
));

export function reducer(state: BeerState | undefined, action: Action) {
  return beerReducer(state, action);
}
```

What I'm retrieving from selecting beers from the store:

```
{
  beers: {
    beers: [
      ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I finally figured it out. I needed to adjust my state tree and add some selectors to select the beers from the store.

Here is my updated NgRx code where changes are commented:

beer-list.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-beer-list',
  templateUrl: './beer-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./beer-list.component.css']
})
export class BeerListComponent implements OnInit {
  public beers$: Observable<Beer[]>;
  
  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.beers$ = this.store.select(selectBeers); // Using selector here
    this.store.dispatch(getBeersOnTap());
  }
}
```

app.state.ts (new file)

```
export interface AppState {
  beerState: BeerState
}
```

beer.selectors.ts (new file)

```
const selectBeerState = (state: AppState) => state.beerState;

export const selectBeers = createSelector(
    selectBeerState,
    (state) => state.beers
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `beerReducer`  is probably added to a `beers` feature? So you will have to select the beer state first.

```
   this.beers$ = this.store.select((state: AppState) => state.beers.beers);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Found a workaround which is close to what you're proposing. However I would like to select from store by: `((state: BeerState) => state.beers`. The `StoreModule` is defined in app.module.ts as: `StoreModule.forRoot(beers: beerReducer)`